# getting error for Ghostscript when converting pdf to image

Tags: python-3.x, image, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to read a PDF and write to an image. There's not a lot of documentation out there but I tried these examples:

```
import ghostscript
import locale

def pdf2jpeg(pdf_input_path, jpeg_output_path):
    args = ["pdf2jpeg", # actual value doesn't matter
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-sDEVICE=jpeg",
            "-r144",
            "-sOutputFile=" + jpeg_output_path, pdf_input_path]

    encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
    args = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args]
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)

pdf2jpeg('input.pdf', 'output.jpeg')
```

And I get the error:

```
partially initialized module 'ghostscript' has no attribute 'Ghostscript' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

In order to install, I did this and it installed version 0.6, which is the latest.

```
pip install ghostscript
```

As per the documentation, I have the requirements (I'm running Python 3.8 Anaconda Spyder)

https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/

To check what methods are available:

```
dir(ghostscript)
Out[30]: 
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 'ghostscript',
 'locale',
 'pdf2jpeg',
 'sys']
```

Is there something else I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I named my script ghostscript.py. I just needed to rename it.